# How to ignore first Interval on first run of System.Windows.Form.Timer?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a timer that repeats at 1 second intervals. Users can `Start()` or `Stop()` the timer.

```cs
System.Windows.Form.Timer timer = new();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
{
  // Perform the action...
}
```

The problem is that in case of `timer.Stop()` it reacts immediately after pressing, but in case of `timer.Start()` it works after 1 second. This may feel strange to users.

So I solved it like this:

```cs
System.Windows.Form.Timer timer = new();
timer.Interval = 1;
timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
{
  if (timer.Interval == 1)
  {
    timer.Interval = 1000;
  }

  // Perform the action...
}
```

```cs
private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timer.Stop();
  timer.Interval = 1;
}
```

However, there is a problem that the timer's Interval must be continuously set to 1. One timer is fine, but having multiple complicates things.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Why not just call the same method immediately before starting the `Timer` that you call on `Tick`?

Comment: To elaborate on @jmcilhinney's comment - Instead of having your timer execute an anonymous method on tick, create a named method for it to run, and simply call it when the user starts the timer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks to you, I solved the problem, and I left a way in a post :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following comments from **@jmcilhinney** and **@Zohar Peled**, I solved it like this:

```cs
System.Windows.Form.Timer timer = new();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
{
  StartOnFirstTimer();
}
```

```cs
private void StartOnFirstTimer()
{
  // Perform the action...
}
```

```cs
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  StartOnFirstTimer();
  timer.Start();
}
```

It is extracted the part corresponding to the timer's Tick event into a method and call it before starting it.